# Ember Data: Allow Embedded ID for Record

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

While using the `RESTAdapter`, I have an `Organization` model which is to be embedded in the response.  It appears that the default implementation of the `Ember.RESTAddapter` sends the `id`, using the same model name, but not as an object (this currently 'works'):

> POST/PUT api/v1/item/{id}

```
{
    "item" {
        id: "1029383829"
        ...
        organization: "26044097612186763401268824297"
    }
}
```

I have consulted the documentation, and found that the mixin `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` should do this, coupled with declaring `embedded: "always"` on the `attrs` or the `Serializer`:

*models/item.js*

```
var Item = DS.Model.extend({
    ...,
    organization: DS.belongsTo("organization", {embedded: "always"})
});
```

*serializers/item.js*:

```
var ItemSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
        attrs: {
            organisation: {serialize: "id", embedded: "always"}
        }
    }
);
```

However, when deserializing records, Ember Data complains, saying that it expected an object, but just got a string:

> Assertion Failed: Expected an object as `data` in a call to push for
>   app@model:organization: , but was 26044097612186763401268824297

Ultimately, I would prefer a system, likened to **sideloading**, wherein an additional attribute, post-fixed "_id", describes the corresponding `id` of an embedded record:

```
{
    "item": {
        id: 1,
        name: "name",
        organization_id: "26044097612186763401268824297"
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I allow serializing and deserializing embedded `id` sideloading for my `Organization` model?

Comment: You don't need to specify `setialize: 'id'` on `attrs.organisation` as it is serializer's default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually embedding the record, you're just specifying the id, in that case you should mark it as async.

```
var Item = DS.Model.extend({
    ...,
    organization: DS.belongsTo("organization", {async: true})
});
```

And remove your embedded records implementation.

Comment: The ``async: true`` prevented the error from occurring, but ``POST``, and ``UPDATE`` requests don't specify explicitly when an ``id`` is being included or the object itself (looking to get ``organization_id``).  Is there a way to do this?